# very this / this very

Tags: word-usage

*Then they need to insert a security token, sent to their email address to verify **very this**.*

Is that correct? I want to express that it is to verify exactly the email address just mentioned. If it is wrong, how do I express that without repeating email address again?

Comment: Where is the "very" coming from? Why is it there? What is "this"?

Comment: Like "this very issue" or "The car has history. This very car won the Rally Dakar"

Comment: In those cases, "very" is being used for emphasis. It doesn't really work as a word-substitution the way you want it to. If you were going to write the sentence using "email address twice", how would you phrase it?

Comment: What does the security token verify?

Comment: @Catija yep, you got me, that is exactly what I tried. When using it twice I would write: Then they need to insert a security token, sent to their email address to verify this very email address. Sounds strange to me, but I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: I think you'll have better luck by rearranging the sentence: "To verify their email address, they are sent a security token, which needs to be inserted in/on/at [place to insert token]." Or maybe it's "which needs to be inserted by following a link in the email"... something like that.

Comment: @Catija I went with: "To verify their email address, they need to insert a security token, sent to this exact address." Is that ok? Thank you and also thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> *Then they need to insert a security token, sent to their email address to verify <strike>very this</strike>.

No. This is not just non-idiomatic, it's difficult if not impossible to understand what you mean without an explanation.

> Then they need to insert a security token, sent to their email address to verify this very email address.

This is a correct use of *very* as an adjective. *Very* in the sense of “the one just mentioned, emphatically” is an adjective, it needs a noun after it. But the sentence sounds clumsy.

> Then they need to insert a security token, sent to their email address to verify the address.

That sounds right, linguistically speaking. But from a technical point of view it doesn't make sense to me: a *security token* is a physical object (at least in this context, but the sentence claims that the security token is sent to an email address. If the token is some kind of verification code (a nonce, in technical terms), and you don't want to use the technical term “nonce”, then you can call if a (one-time) verification code, and that code would be *entered* or *typed* rather than *inserted*.

> Then they need to type a verification code which was sent to their email address to verify the address.

If that's not what you mean then this sentence needs more work.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you may be looking for is

> Then they need to insert a security token, which is sent to their email address, **for verification**.
>   Then they need to insert a security token **for verification**, which is sent to their email address.

Comment: Needs some commas "Then they need to insert a security token, which is sent to their email address, for verification."

Comment: I want to express that it is not just for verification but to verify that exact email address just mentioned

Comment: Errr, it is email address verification: "for verification *( of the email address )*", what other verification would it be for?

Comment: You know, I know, everyone else should know, but...

Comment: @Peter It could be a verification of the security token. Or of the user's identity, or other concepts that were mentioned in previous sentences.